# Getting the header name for matching data

Tags: excel

I have a list of e-mail addresses in one sheet (sheet 1) and a few columns on another sheet (sheet 2) which contain the e-mail addresses. Each column has been used to categorise the e-mail addresses. So:

**Sheet 1**

```
a@b.com
c@d.com
z@y.com
```

**Sheet 2**

```
|  Group 1  |  Group 2  |
-------------------------
| a@b.com   | c@d.com   |
| z@y.com   |           |
-------------------------
```

What I'm trying to do is:

- Match the name on sheet 1 to a range/array on sheet 2
- If a match is found, then populate the adjacent cell with the name of the header

Thus:

**What Sheet 1 should look like:**

```
a@b.com | Group 1
c@d.com | Group 2
z@y.com | Group 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:A,1,0)=TRUE),IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!B:B,1,0)=TRUE),"No Group",Sheet2!$B$1),Sheet2!$A$1)
```

That should work for you to put in Sheet1, Column B.

Comment: The post mentions a "few" columns.  This won't work if there's more than the two in the example.

Comment: I've tried this and it worked but Doug is quite correct: extending this would be troublesome. Thank you kwilmarth for the quick suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that your list on Sheet 2 is within A1:Z1000, with headers in row 1.  It also assumes that your list on Sheet 1 has headers in row 1, with the first email starting on row 2.

First it checks if the email is found.  If so, it calculates the column it's in, using the wonderful Sumproduct function, and then uses that column as an Index to the first row and returns the Group number.

Copy into Sheet1, B2 and drag down as necessary:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$2:$Z$1000,A2)=0,"not found",INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$1,SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!$A$2:$Z$1000=A2)*COLUMN(Sheet2!$A$2:$Z$1000))))
```

Comment: I'll try this out. I recently discovered the wonders of sumproduct with some interesting syntax `=sumproduct(--(...),(...))`. Any idea what the `--` does?

Comment: According to this post: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=77119, "it coerces TRUE/FALSE to 1/0 and numbers seen as text to true numbers." Not necessary in this case, as the multiplication has the same effect on the True/False values.